# Setting NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0 on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, cuda, modprobe

I've run both nsight profiler and nsight compute and i get the same issue:

```
nvprof log: /home/centos/nvvp_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.nvidia.viper/launch/0/nvprof_21332.log
==21332== Warning: ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM - The user does not have permission to profile on the target device. See the following link for instructions to enable permissions and get more information: https://developer.nvidia.com/ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM 
==21332== Warning: Some profiling data are not recorded. Make sure cudaProfilerStop() or cuProfilerStop() is called before application exit to flush profile data.
```

I followed the link to understand what the issue was, apparently there is some flag that is set for security reasons to stop profiling.  Fine, what is the work around? Use this command every time, whilist disabling a bunch of stuff first:

```
modprobe nvidia NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0
```

Or do the following once in modprobe.d:

```
options nvidia "NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0"
```

and restart.

I made sure I could get these programs to run in sudo (it works), but I don't want to do that to use the programs. So I go and add a file that says this in modprobe.d (cuda_settings.conf):

```
options nvidia "NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0"
```

and of course I get the same error again.

Then I try to do the following, since another Nvidia guide references a slightly different command:

```
options nvidia NVreg_RegistryDwords="NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0"
```

That... also doesn't work, same exact error.

```
==21332== Warning: ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM - The user does not have permission to profile on the target device. See the following link for instructions to enable permissions and get more information: https://developer.nvidia.com/ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM
```

Also tried `options nvidia NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers=0`, again to no avail.

Is there something else I need in order get this setting applied on startup? How do I actually make sure this value is set?

Comment: Seeing the same thing on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the initial RAM disk did the trick for me:

```
sudo dracut --force
```